# Perfect square with negative constant term

Tags: square-numbers

If $x$ and $b$ are positive integers and it is also given that the expression $x^2 + \dfrac{4x}{b^2} - 4$ is a perfect square.  what is a good method to analyse the expression with the knowledge that it is a perfect square and $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, so that ultimately we can try to get some kind of relation or constraint between $a$ and $b$?
One relation I could think  was $(\dfrac{4x}{b^2}-4) = 0$, so that expression would reduce to $x^2$, which is a perfect square. but is it the only possibility and would like  to know other possibilities if any?

$$\textbf{ Here is the attempt I made, please point out the faulty logic.}$$
A perfect square expression $(x+a)^2$ is expanded as $ f = x^2 + 2ax + a^2$ and $ f' = 2x + 2a $.

 Further $ (f - af') = x^2 - a^2 $ and by gcd property $(x + a)$ is a factor of $ (f - af') $.

Using the above, if $g = x^2 + \dfrac{4x}{b^2} - 4$ ,

 then $ (g - \dfrac{2}{b^2}g') = x^2 - \dfrac{8}{b^2} - 4$.
 The expression $ (g - \dfrac{2}{b^2}g')$ should have a factor equivalent to $(x + a)$, if $g = x^2 + \dfrac{4x}{b^2} - 4$ is a perfect square.
 This would mean that the term $( \dfrac{8}{b^4} + 4)$ in $ (g - \dfrac{2}{b^2}g')$ equates to $a^2$ term in $ (f - af') $. 
Therefore the term  $ (\dfrac{8}{b^4} + 4)$  must be perfect square and given that b is a positive integer.

For $b=1$, $ (\dfrac{8}{b^4} + 4)$  evaluates to 12, which is not a perfect square.

For $b=2$, $ (\dfrac{8}{b^4} + 4)$  evaluates to 6, which is not a perfect square.

For all other b, $ (\dfrac{8}{b^4} + 4)$  are not even integers.

This contradicts $ (\dfrac{8}{b^4} + 4)$ being a perfect square and in turn establishes that there is no $(x+a)$ type factor in $ (g - \dfrac{2}{b^2}g')$. So this means that for the expression $(x^2 + \dfrac{4x}{b^2} - 4)$  to be a perfect square , there is the only  possibility of it reducing to $x^2$. This means $(\dfrac{4x}{b^2} - 4) = 0$.

Kindly point out any flaws in the proof.

Comment: One way to go would be to let $f(x)=(x-a)^2$

Comment: I'm terrified of using derivatives in questions about integers, because there are so many cases where it's not possible. But I don't immediately see anything wrong with your statement.